# How to detect if the user has iCloud enabled for my app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6, icloud

I have developed an iCloud enabled iPhone App, but the issue I m facing is that even if user turn off iCloud backup for my App then also it takes back up on iCloud and reflect changes on my other devices, so I want to know that how can I get that my App is iCloud enabled or not.

It's specifically for App not for Device, if device is iCloud enabled but my App is turned off then it should not take any back ups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use this to check the status of your iCloud whether it is enabled or not .

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
NSURL *iCloudURL = [fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil]; 
NSLog(@"%@", [iCloudURL absoluteString]); 

if(iCloudURL){ 
NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore *iCloudStore = [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore]; 
[iCloudStore setString:@"Success" forKey:@"iCloudStatus"]; 
[iCloudStore synchronize]; // For Synchronizing with iCloud Server 
NSLog(@"iCloud status : %@", [iCloudStore stringForKey:@"iCloudStatus"]); 
}
```

This will tell you whether it is ON/OFF :)

Comment: it always return Success whether App is turn off for back up or not.

Comment: With regards to the 'URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:' method, Apple has updated their docs: "Important: Do not call this method from your app’s main thread. Because this method might take a nontrivial amount of time to set up iCloud and return the requested URL, you should always call it from a secondary thread. To determine if iCloud is available, especially at launch time, call the ubiquityIdentityToken method instead."

Comment: Apple has since updated their docs to read: "Important: Do not call this method from your app’s main thread. Because this method might take a nontrivial amount of time to set up iCloud and return the requested URL, you should always call it from a secondary thread. To determine if iCloud is available, especially at launch time, check the value of the NSURLRelationship property instead."

Comment: Just a note this approach does NOT help if you are using the key/value store. I have everything enabled and working using the key/value store yet this iCloudURL returns nil.

Answer (score 10):

I recommend using this instead if you are using key-value and not document storage.

```
id iCloudToken = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] ubiquityIdentityToken];
if ( iCloudToken != nil) {
// User has enabled icloud in your app...
} else {
// Icloud is not enabled for your app...
}
```

Now the reason i recommend the method above is that in the new Xcode compiler you can now dictate if you are going to use document storage or not. If you choose to only use key-value storage, the NSFileManager check will fail as you will not have the container identifier defined in the entitlements. However, ubiquityIdentityToken will always exists if the user has allowed your app to run meaning it will always fire true or false if the user has allowed your app access to iCloud.

Comment: I'm finding that checking the token's validity works for accounts that have not updated to iCloud Drive. But the token always seems to be valid for accounts that have upgraded to iCloud Drive - even if the user disables your app in iCloud Drive settings.

Comment: Yes but disabling the app in iCloud drive is not the same as removing the apps access to iCloud.  You can configure the app to have access to iCloud but prevents it's iCloud container from being visible in iCloud Drive.

Comment: Even after turning off iCloud Drive for my app, the token coming back from this is unchanged. I don't think this can be used to detect the current state.