# Detect iCloud availability change on OS X

Tags: xcode, macos, icloud

I have a pair of app, one for iOS and one for OS X, that share data through CloudKit private database and iCloud key-value store if the user chooses to, he's logged in and iCloud Data & Documents is enabled for my app and it all works fine with iCloud enabled or disabled from the beginning.

On the iOS side I can detect user choice in `Settings` app using `ubiquityIdentityToken` and `URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier("iCloud.my.default.container.for.osx")` from `NSFileManager` to detect if user is logged in and if he enabled Data & Documents and they are `nil` when expected: when they are nor CloudKit nor Key-Value store works (as expected).

When changing these two settings while the app is running it is terminated so I can check for changes when it's opened again, so no problem. When I tested the same code on OS X I found that if I turn off Data & Documents in `System Preferences` the app is not killed but I guess it's the intended behavior, but even if I listen for iCloud availability change using

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "checkiCloud:", name: NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

my app is not notified. If I manually check iCloud availability, i.e. by restarting the app, I found that `ubiquityIdentityToken` is not `nil` and that's correct as I am logged in iCloud, but even `URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier("iCloud.my.default.container.for.osx")` is not `nil` and that's not what I expect.

Is this the expected behavior on OS X? If so, how can I check if iCloud is disabled and get notified when something changes? Or is this a bug (I'm testing on El Capitan)?

**UPDATE:** Disabling iCloud Drive all together make the notification fire and `URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier()` return `nil` so I guess it's a bug.

**UPDATE:** I've filed a BugReport to Apple: #22973458

Comment: Why isn't `URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier()` not being `nil` what you expect? In `OS X` you're supposed to use an `NSDocument` object instead (If your app is document based).

Comment: When I disable Data & Documents in `System Preferences` for my app I still get a URL, but this only happens only on OS X. The same done on iOS give me `nil` when calling `URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier()`. The app is not document based, it uses a Core Data database that I keep in sync with CloudKit.

Comment: I believe the value you are seeing returned might be your apps local default container, not sure. You'll probably want to use `NSURLRelationship` to notify `NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification` whether iCloud is disabled or the identity has changed.

Comment: I pass a specific value to `URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier()` (I'll update my question) but that value is the default container, so it's the same problem I guess. Should I use a container that is not default for both of the app, but Apple says in documentation that's not possible? Can you post an example on how to do that?

Comment: If you can point to the place in the documentation that mentions it I'd be interested to see what it says. I don't think you need to use different containers; Is your goal just check whether or not iCloud is disabled and/or if it's a different iCloud identity?

Comment: I'm not able to find it anymore, maybe it was outdated documentation and got removed. Yes, exactly.

Comment: Okay, see `NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification`, as it states: "When your app receives this notification, get the new token from the `NSURLRelationship`property. The value of that token is nil if the user has disabled iCloud. There is no userInfo dictionary."

Comment: I got that but for which object I get that property?

Comment: Check [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15082959/499581), it maybe what you're looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work: the value saved is retrieved successfully and `synchronize()` return true

Answer (score 1):

If you are building Document-based OS X app, you can use

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] ubiquityIdentityToken])
//iCloud Drive is enabled
```

to check whether or not iCloud Drive is enabled for the device.